# Axon - PostgreSQL - Where is the payload in the event store?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, axon, axon-framework

I am currently setting up an event-store with Axon-framework in PostgreSQL (spring boot, axon-spring-boot-starter, axon-server-connector removed from the dependency).

The system loads as expected and I am able to see commands, events and event handlers working as expected.

The issue is when I want to see the contents of my events in the event table (domain_event_entry) .

I would expect that the 'payload' column in the table containing all the events that I persisted in the event store, but I am just seeing numbers: something like this:

global_index | event_identifier                     | metadata |payload_type |
1            | 7c23e693-558b-4013-b64f-3f272cb0102a |19435     |19436|

Also, I believe that the metadata should contain something other tha n an integer.

Is this correct? Am I missing some extra configuration?

Comment: As Yvonne states, it's a problem with PostgreSQL. As an optimization, it moves (B/C)LOBs to a different table, replacing them with a so-called OID (object identifier). Due to this, you lose insight into what's stored in the BLOB. The blog Yvonne shares clearly explain how to mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Postgres uses TOAST (The oversized attribute storage technique). How to make this better readable can be found in this [blogpost](https://blog.trifork.com/2017/10/09/axon-postgresql-without-toast/)